# How to find and view Android Studio imported libraries

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

So I imported some libraries and I want to see the code in them. But I cannot find them.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio, in the project pane on the left, you can change the view from Android to Project, Project Files, Packages, etc.

Change that view to Project or Project Files, and you will find all libraries added to your project.

If you do not have the project pane enabled, goto View then Tools Window then Project. Or just press Alt + 1